# How to return 404 in case of action argument's type mismatch in web api?

Tags: asp.net-web-api, filter, http-status-codes

I have a web api application and I have an http post action taking dto as following :

```
public class Account
{
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public string Email { get; set; }

    public int Age { get; set; }
}
```

But using Postman I can pass it like this:

> {"Name":"Simple Code",Email:"SimpleCode@gmail.com",Age:null}

When I send the request it sends Age as null.

How can I get my web api returning 404 without sending the request or am I forced to validate that inside my code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi the most fast way for me is:

Mark as [Required] your DTO

```
public class Account
{
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [Required(AllowEmptyString = false)]
    public string Email { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public int Age { get; set; }
}
```

then in your API method

```
public IHttpActionResult Post([FromBody] mydto){

   // if model is not validated return 400 bad request
   if(!ModelState.IsValid) return BadRequest(ModelState);

   //or if is here it's ok

   //return 200 OK 
   Ok(mydto);
}
```